# How to modify the multibar chart from getting "Error: Invalid value for <path> attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)""?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

```
var dayToDateConverter = function (day) {
        var mSec = day * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        var m = moment(mSec).utc();

        if (m.format("MM/DD/YY") === 'Invalid Date') {
            return;
        }
        return m.format("MM/DD/YY");
    };




CUSTOMERTRACGRAPH: {
            "options": {
                chart: {
                    type: 'multiBarChart',
                    grouped: true,
                    showControls: false,
                    height: 400,
                    color: ["#f4a460", "#d27b6f"],
                    margin: {
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 60,
                        left: 45
                    },
                    clipEdge: true,
                    staggerLabels: true,
                    transitionDuration: 1000,
                    tooltips: true,
                    tooltipContent: function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
                        return '<p>' + key + ': ' + y + '</p>';
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        axisLabel: 'Date (MM/DD/YY)',
                        axisLabelDistance: 10,
                        showMaxMin: true,
                        tickFormat: function (d) {
                            return d;
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        axisLabel: 'Count',
                        axisLabelDistance: -20,
                        tickFormat: function (d) {
                            return d3.format(',.f')(d);
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: []
            }
```

The data format is something like: `[
{"key":"New","values":[{"x":17136,"y":5178}]},
{"key":"Returning","values":[{"x":17136,"y":0}]}
]`
I'm calling some API, and in it's success callback I'm populating the data of the chart and getting this error:

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(NaN,NaN)"

Is there any possible solution to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you sure that your are giving right format?

Comment: It is working when I tried this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/nCa1jH8Lx8u2qpSmLhlB?p=preview

Comment: thanks...but I'm still getting the NaN error

Comment: Can you share your code snippet or jsfiddle?